# How to display an input box based on choices in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I have a parameterized job in Jenkins. I am taking choice as one of the parameters. The first two choices be `choice1` and `choice2`. Now I want to add a third choice option that is `custom` such that if the user selects this, then an input box appears and the user can input the value of the variable instead of choosing from the first 2 options. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look into [extended-choice-parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/extended-choice-parameter/). The page also contains an example

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this. I am new to Jenkins and Groovy.

Comment: You might check e.g. https://medium.com/@rijoalvi/jenkins-dynamic-parameters-using-extended-choice-parameter-plugin-and-groovy-1a6ffc41063f this explains it pretty well.

Comment: This article also explains on how to change options dynamically. I want to add a string parameter in my Jenkins job based on the choice selected.